# I am awaiting for a return Promise from a class method from a module i am creating and i get it, but in a weird context. How can i await it properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, es6-promise

So I am creating a module with a class method(**schedule**) with async function awaiting the return

```
//SCHEDULER.JS//

class Schedule {
  constructor(project_id, queue_id) {
    this.project_id = project_id;
    this.queue_id = queue_id;
  }


  //ASYNC METHOD 1
  schedule = async (date, rquest) => {

    const project = this.project_id;
    const queue = this.queue_id;
    const location = "us-central1";
    const url = rquest.url;
    const payload = rquest.body;

    // Construct the fully qualified queue name.
    const parent = client.queuePath(project, location, queue);

    const task = {
      httpRequest: {
        httpMethod: rquest.method,
        url,
        headers: rquest.headers,
      },
    };

    try {
      const request = await { parent, task };
      const [response] = await client.createTask(request);
 
      console.log("<THIS IS THE PROJECT ID> :", response.name);
      return `${response.name}`;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("we have an error amigo!", error);
    }
  };


  //ASYNC METHOD 2
  delete = async (one) => {
    return console.log("delete function", one);
  };
```

I imported my module on main.js and used my method. Once the results returns, I need to use it as a parameter to another method(delete) on the module I created(Scheduler.js).

```
//main.js//

const task_id = scheduler.schedule(date, request);

scheduler.delete(task_id);
```

task_id is returning a promise and I can't execute scheduler.delete(task_id) because it is pending promise still.

Important: How can I handle this promise properly as I am only tasked to create the module and not the main.js. The people who would create the main.js would just be expected to run my methods without handling promise returns.

Comment: People who use the method simply need to know it returns a promise and have to treat it as such. You can't make a promise synchronous. `scheduler.schedule(date, request).then(scheduler.delete)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TLDR

> task_id is returning a promise

If it's a promise you can await it

```
//main.js//

async function main () {
    const task_id = await scheduler.schedule(date, request); // <--- THIS!

    scheduler.delete(task_id);
}

main();
```

#### Await & promises:

In fact, the `await` keyword **only** works on promises (you can await non-promises but it is a no-op by design). That's the whole reason for `await` - an alternative way to use promises. Because of this functions marked with the `async` keyword always returns a promise.

Or if you prefer not to await then just use it as a promise:

```
//main.js//

scheduler.schedule(date, request)
         .then(task_id => scheduler.delete(task_id));
```

Comment: Thank you. I am under the impression that they'd use my method without creating an async function, but there is just no way. they really should await for my return from method otherwise the delete method won't work. I appreciate it. Thank you for answering my newbie Q.

Comment: The corollary is that if it is **not** a promise you **cannot await** it. A lot of people are confused by this expecting `await` to work with things like `setTimeout()` which is asynchronous but does not return a promise. There is a big difference between "async" as a short form of "asynchronous" functions and functions marked with the `async` keyword which are promise returning functions.

Comment: @Ruvin You're welcome. Hopefully this answer will help others as well when they google this issue. Thank you for asking this

Answer (score 1):

You can create another function, which will be called from main.js, and inside this function call your actual function and in then function of Promise return the value.